# Zero output in PINNs when using a dictionary layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to implement PINNs method with a dictionary layer in keras library for solving a PDE. I have prepared a neural network and in its last layer I have put a Fourier dictionary for faster convergence. But during training, the loss function is almost fixed with a large value and it can be said that the network does not learned, the output is almost zero. Does anyone know what my mistake is? And why does my network reach a near-zero output value with a high error?

```
##########################################################################
@tf.function
def fourier_basic(x):
    l=0
    u=1
    basis_num = 21
    x=(x-l)/(u-l)*2*pi
    s = [tf.ones_like(x)]+[tf.cos(i*x)/i for i in range(1,basis_num // 2 + 1)] + [tf.sin(i*x)/i for i in range(1,basis_num //2+1)]
    s = tf.concat(s,1)
    return s

@tf.function
def custom_layer(inp):

     s = fourier_basic(inp[1])
     return (inp[0]*s)

### model builder function
def DNN_builder(in_shape=2, out_shape=1, n_hidden_layers=10,
                neuron_per_layer=20, actfn="tanh"):
    # input layer
    input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(in_shape,))
    # hidden layers
    hidden = [tf.keras.layers.Dense(neuron_per_layer, activation=actfn)(input_layer)]
    for i in range(n_hidden_layers-1):
        new_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(neuron_per_layer,
                                          activation=actfn,
                                          activity_regularizer=None)(hidden[-1])
        hidden.append(new_layer)
    # output layer
    X = tf.keras.layers.Dense(21, activation=None)(hidden[-1])
    Lambda_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(custom_layer, name="lambda_layer")([X,input_layer[:,:1]])

    output_layer= tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None)(Lambda_layer )
    
    # building the model
    name = f"DNN-{n_hidden_layers}"
    model = tf.keras.Model(input_layer, output_layer, name=name)
    return model

################################################################################

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
model = DNN_builder(2, 1, 5, 64, "tanh")
```

Iterations and loss value :

```
    0 ,Best Loss:  810.9676089,
  100 ,Best Loss:  2.3435999, 
  200 ,Best Loss:  2.1878275,
  300 ,Best Loss:  2.1411654,
  400 ,Best Loss:  2.1252907,
  500 ,Best Loss:  2.1191618,
  600 ,Best Loss:  2.1157855, 
  700 ,Best Loss:  2.1134179, 
  800 ,Best Loss:  2.1116254,
```